# Importing DirectXTex

Tags: directx

I am returning to an old DX9 project and have found a lot of my libraries have since been deprecated, specifically all D3DX files.

I'm trying to import DirectXTex to replace D3DX11Tex.

I've downloaded the library from its github page [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex)

To add it I've added the file path to DirectXTex to additional dependencies but when I include it in my texture header file it's underlined in red.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is it necessary to include additional dependencies in header files? I haven't open up visual studio in a long time and am a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio and the Windows SDK are you using? I have fairly detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/DirectXTex#adding-to-a-vs-solution).

> You should take a few moments to read [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/) as you may find that [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) is a better fit for your project needs than [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki) or vice-versa.